# C++ thread waiting times

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

Is there a way to get the time a thread has been **WAITING** during its life (in C++/windows)?
(I've asked before about the working time, but getting the waiting time would be much better :) )

Using `GetThreadTimes` is not enough for me because I need a high resultion (way better than 100 microsec, more towards 5-10 microsec or even less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Call GetThreadTimes().
2. Add together kernel time and user time.
3. Subtract creation time from now.
4. Subtract value found in step 2 from that found in step 3 and you have your answer.

Comment: Yep, I thought of this, but I need a rather high resoulution than the one of GetThreadTimes (which is 100 microsec). Also this method would have a bias of the time between I suspend the thread and "now", it might be a few microsec and I was hoping to avoid it. :)

Comment: GetThreadTimes resolution is 100 nanoseconds (= 0.1 microseconds). Though that does not guarantee that it is precise to 100 nanoseconds, too. I'm not sure if there exists _any_ reliable timer with that precision under Windows at all, at least not unless you say "only Windows 7 on the most recent processor generation" (resolution is not necessarily precision).

Comment: Great! I don't know how I saw a 100 *micro* resolution. thanks :)